# Where or how I see the various SystemColors in the different themes?

Tags: .net, winforms, themes, colors

We're designing a winforms app, and in order to match its appearance to the system theme we're trying to restrict ourselves to the colours in the `SystemColors` class.  However, it's sometimes hard to choose appropriate colours without knowing what colour they correspond to in the different themes.  I can see the palette for the current theme in Visual Studio, but is there somewhere I can see all the palettes at once?  Ideally I'd like a table showing the colours for each of classic, XP (Blue, Olive, Silver, Royale) and Vista.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to set the color pallet, but if this helps, you can test which color scheme is active via System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles:

```
if(VisualStyleInformation.ColorScheme == "NormalColor")
{
    // blue color scheme
}
else if(VisualStyleInformation.ColorScheme == "HomeStead")
{
    //olive green   
}
else if (VisualStyleInformation.ColorScheme == "Metallic")
{
    //silver
}
```